# Install PHP 7.3 in Debian jessie

Tags: linux, debian, php, debian-jessie

Good morning guys!
I am trying to install PHP 7.3 on a Debian jessie machine, however it gives a problem with some dependencies when I use the **apt-get install php7.3** command. I have already tried to install all the dependencies that apt informs that it needs, but it did not work. I also changed my /etc/apt/source.list file and did an apt-get update and then an apt-get upgrade, but it did not work. The message it gives me when trying apt-get install php7.3 is as follows:

```
Reading package lists ... Ready
Building dependency tree
Reading status information ... Ready
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that
you asked for an impossible situation or, if you are using the
unstable distribution, that some required packages were not
created yet or were taken from the "Incoming".
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have mismatched dependencies:
 php7.3: Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.3 but will not install or
                   php7.3-fpm but will not be installed or
                   php7.3-cgi but will not install
E: Impossible to fix problems, you kept (hold) broken packages.
```

Has anyone experienced this and could you help me, please?

Thank you!
[Error trying apt-get install php7.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCqGY.png)
[Error trying to install dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8FiF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, update and autoremove the outdated package. This will do it for you:

https://github.com/TurboLabIt/zzupdate

Then, I guess you're missing the repo. Remove what you did and run these:

```
apt purge --auto-remove php* -y -qq
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
    apt update -qq

    ## mcrypt is discontinued since PHP 7.2
    apt install php${PHP_VER}-fpm php${PHP_VER}-cli php${PHP_VER}-common php${PHP_VER}-mbstring php${PHP_VER}-gd php${PHP_VER}-intl php${PHP_VER}-xml php${PHP_VER}-mysql php${PHP_VER}-zip php${PHP_VER}-curl -y -qq
```

For a ready-to-use solution give this a shot: https://github.com/TurboLabIt/webstackup